# Qscintilla2 AutoCompletion and AutoIdentation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qscintilla

I implemented this class in my project:

```
class ScriptEditorTextBox(QsciScintilla):

def __init__(self, parent):
    QsciScintilla.__init__(self)

    #Lexer
    lexer = QsciLexerPython()

    #AutoCompletion
    api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(lexer)
    api.add('aLongString')
    api.add('aLongerString')
    api.add('aDifferentString')
    api.add('sOmethingElse')
    api.prepare()

    self.setLexer(lexer)
    self.setAutoCompletionThreshold(1)
    self.setAutoCompletionSource(QsciScintilla.AcsAPIs)

    #LineHighlight
    self.setCaretLineVisible(True)
    self.setCaretLineBackgroundColor(QColor("gainsboro"))

    #AutoIndentation
    self.setAutoIndent(True)
    self.setIndentationGuides(True)
    self.setIndentationsUseTabs(True)
    self.setIndentationWidth(4)

    #Margins
    self.setMarginsBackgroundColor(QColor("gainsboro"))
    self.setMarginsFont(QFont("Consolas", 9, 87)) 
    self.setMarginLineNumbers(1, True)
    self.setMarginLineNumbers(2, False)
    self.setMarginWidth(1, QString().setNum(10))
    self.setMarginWidth(2, 10)
    self.connect(self, SIGNAL("linesChanged()"), self._linesChanged)

def _linesChanged(self):
    width = QString().setNum(self.lines() * 10)
    self.setMarginWidth(1, width)
```

Everything starts fine, but when I'm pressing enter after : it just does not auto indent. And, also no auto-completion (but I don't even know what should it autocomplete).

I'll be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Both problems are caused by failing to keep a proper reference to the lexer.

The example code will work if you do this:

```
    lexer = QsciLexerPython(self)
```

or this:

```
    self.lexer = QsciLexerPython()
    ...
    api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(self.lexer)
    ...
    self.setLexer(self.lexer)
```

Comment: Thanks much, that works. But it still doesn't chach my python std libraries, it autocompletes only from current document. And I can't figure out what changes the autoindentation after [: and enter], cause now there is no autoindent.

Comment: @Mad.Lobster. Well, obviously it cannot auto-complete from apis that you haven't loaded. And I don't know what what you mean about auto-indentation: it works exactly as expected for me.

Comment: I don't understand why but my auto-completion only works if I put self as parent, AND setLexer().